# OpenGL glScissors center of coordinate system

Tags: opengl

My issue is that I'm trying to do the glScissors call to cut off the screen draw area, but the center of coordinate system for this function in window space is bottom left corner of the screen.
Is there a way to change the origin of the center? I want the function to work in relation to the top left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can make a function that transforms from one corrdinate system to another

```
void scissorTopLeft(int x, int y, int w, int h, int screenHeight)
{
    glScissor(x, screenHeight-h-y, w, h);
}
```